# Ways to compare two CCSprite's runAction

Tags: objective-c, cocos2d-iphone, ccsprite, kobold2d

I have a CCSprite "_wo1" and it has a BOOL property "attack". I have the following code in my update method and I want it to constantly check if "attack" is YES or NO and make my sprite do different kinds of runAction.

So my question is:

**How to compare two runAction? I tried "==" and "isEqual" and they are not working..**

```
MySprite *_wo1 = ... // initialize _wo1 using my own class that sub-classed CCSprite
    if (![_wo1 attack])
    {
        _wo1.position = ccp(_wo1.position.x + 10 * dt, _wo1.position.y); // walking forward
        if (currentAction == attAction) // currentAction is defined in setting its runAction in the beginning: "currentAction = [wo1 runAction:[s01WalkAction copy]];"
        {
            [_wo1 stopAction:attAction];
            [_wo1 runAction:[walkAction copy]];
        }
    }
    else{
        if (currentAction == walkAction)
        {
            [_wo1 stopAction:walkAction];
            [_wo1 runAction:[attAction copy]];
        }

    }
```

Any helps or suggestions will be highly appreciated. Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can keep an action state of your sprite in the `MySprite` class which easily can tell you which action is used in the sprite.

When you run an action on the sprite just set the state properly. For example :

```
mySprite.actionState = ACTION_WALKING;
```

and then you can easily check which action is used:

```
  if (mySprite.actionState == ACTION_WALKING)
        {
           // Your handling code
        }
```